# Does "POLY-MET" unambiguously describe a capacitor type?

Tags: capacitor

I have a BOM where one of the capacitors is described as .33UF 250V 10% POLY-MET.

I did a search on the term "poly-met" and found a [Cornell Dubilier device](http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Cornell-Dubilier-CDE/935C2W2K-F/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMv1cc3ydrPrF%252bqVmHpyCNVAwAmBGfeDvmw%3d) with that particular designation. It's a metallized polypropylene capacitor, which makes sense of the nickname.

But I'm wondering, couldn't it also mean a metallized polyethylene or poly-other-ene construction as well? Is it a conventional nickname applied to in particular to metallized polypropylene or perhaps the -ene that's used doesn't matter that much for most applications? (In this case its used for high-frequency bypass on a transformer secondary before a bridge rectifier.)

Comment: Polyester it might be.

Comment: Google search for the whole in-caps phrase returns as 1st hit http://www.pdfdoc.ru.stangenzirkel.com/passive-components/capacitors/film-capacitors/polyester-film-capacitors/polyester-film-capacitors-poly-met-250v-33uf-10-tol-146-mef2e334k which is a metallized poly**ester** part. You can confirm whether that makes sense by looking at the footprint of the part on the PCB design you have and comparing with that Xicon datasheet.

Comment: Re: "bypass on a transformer secondary before a bridge rectifier" Why put a 250V part on the secondary? Is this a 380V (or higher) to 240V transformer or something like that?

Comment: Also beware that the same "MET POLY" is used by CDE for their [p*ester X2 caps as well](http://www.mouser.de/ProductDetail/Cornell-Dubilier-CDE/158X105/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMv1cc3ydrPrF9O2k7r3G2yZ77cSwMfOb7A%3d) which would be consistent with the Xicon part. I doubt the audiophile style polyprop cap you found first is the one actually in this power application.

Comment: @RespawnedFluff - Yes, I ended up with the same conclusion. I think the polyester is the type they had in mind for power bypass.  I'm going to specify one of these [TDK models](http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/EPCOS-TDK/B32521C3334J/?qs=p%2F12KT2rJdXJog1WUSgl7w%3D%3D).

Comment: @RespawnedFluff - Regarding the working voltage, I'm not sure why they would specify so high except maybe the price difference is small and they wanted it to withstand the occasional line spike. The working voltage there is about 12VAC, so that seems like a pretty big margin. It's an interesting question though. Maybe its worth me posting a separate question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first *guess* for what "poly-met" means was "metalized polypropylene".  However, using that abbreviation when its important this be understood clearly without additional information is irresponsible engineering.

Any competent BOM will show a part number, which is the real definition of the part.  The description is to give you a quick idea of what part to expect.  This could be a manufacturer's part number, a distributor stock number, or a in-house partnumber.  Preferably, more than one of these is filled in.  Either way, look these up to get the definitive answer.